# What is the Set defined by this Regular Expression?

Tags: regular-language

I am trying to go through regular expression and language questions however, this one seems to have gotten me stuck.

Can somebody help?

I am trying to write out the set that is defined by this regular expression:

[image]

Comment: Well, there are two choices for the first grouping, and two independent choices for the second grouping. If you can have a soda or a beer, and a hamburger or a hot dog, how many possible meals are there?

Answer (score 1):

To understand this regular expression, lets consider its three parts separately:

> **( a | Ɛ )**    abb   **(a | b)**
>   \**---1----   --2--- ---3---**
>    <sub>this regular expression is defined in three groups/parts using parenthesis</sub>

**Part-1:** Ɛ is a null symbol in regular expression, if it appears with some other symbol (or a group of symbols)  with union operator |  that means that symbol(or group) is option e.g. can be appear or not appear in some strings of language ( Ɛ symbols in FA as edge label defines 'null-transition' — which allows a transformation to a new state without consuming any input symbols).

In your regular expression, first 'a' is written with Ɛ — ( a | Ɛ ) so it is option - it can appear in some string or absent in other. Hence strings generated with using this regular expression either starts with  two 'a' or one 'a'.

**Part-2:**  Sub-string 'aab' always appears in all possible string using this regular expression.

so strings can be in two possible forms:

> 1. aabb(a|b)
> 2. abb(a|b)

**Part-3:**  (a | b)  string either ends with symbol 'a' or symbol 'b'.

if both above forms ends with 'a'

> - aabba
> - abba

if both above forms ends with 'b'

> - aabbb
> - abbb

Of-course it is a finite language and its DFA does not contain any loop. Its DFA for this language { aabba, abba, aabbb, abbb } would be as following:

> [image]